# C# SDK: Facebook wall posts are not appearing on my window form

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I developing a window app where it can get all my Facebook profile wall posts and display it on the list box. I downloaded the codes from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lC7Q2Z2yik but my Facebook wall posts are still not displaying. I can post on my wall through my application, my profile picture and friends are successfully displayed. is there anything I forgot to change/add? any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
private void getMyWallData()
    {
        apiService.AccessToken = myToken.Default.token;

        JSONObject myWallFeed = apiService.Get("/me/feed");
        var wallData = myWallFeed.Dictionary["data"];

        List<JSONObject> myFeeds = wallData.Array.ToList<JSONObject>();

        foreach (var p in myFeeds)
        {

            try
            {
                if (p.Dictionary.ContainsKey("message"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Dictionary["message"].String + " " + p.Dictionary["created_time"].String);
                    listBoxMyWall.Items.Add(p.Dictionary["message"].String);
                    listBoxMyWall.Items.Add("");
                }

                if (p.Dictionary.ContainsKey("comments"))
                {
                    listBoxMyWall.Items.Add("   " + p.Dictionary["comments"].Dictionary["data"].Array[0].Dictionary["from"].Dictionary["name"].String + " " + p.Dictionary["comments"].Dictionary["data"].Array[0].Dictionary["message"].String);
                    listBoxMyWall.Items.Add("");
                }


            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: not sure what i did but now my wall feed can appear however I got the " the given key was not present in the dictionary " pop out message.